# Android OnclickItem listview more detailed info in another activity from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, onitemclicklistener

I want to request data from a database. In the list I want to Display only the title and if you click it I want to show more detailed info. How would I get the position of the ListItem and show the data that belongs to that one list item?
Here's my code:

**FragmentRonde1.java**

```
public class FragmentRonde1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public ListView lv1;
public TextView tv1, tv2;
MyDbHandler db;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

public FragmentRonde1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ronde1, container, false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle("Workshops Ronde 1");

    db = new MyDbHandler(getActivity());

    db.InsertValues();
    final Cursor cursor=db.GetAllData();
    String from [] = new String[]{db.COLUMN_TITLE};
    int to [] = new int[] {R.id.workshopTitle1};
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_layout_workshop, cursor, from, to, 0);

    lv1 = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.Ronde1lv);
    lv1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent listClicked = new Intent(getActivity(), ListClicked.class);
            startActivity(listClicked);

            tv1 = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);
            tv2 = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listClickedDescription);

        }
    });

    return rootview;
    }
}
```

**MyDbHandler.java**

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "workshopDB";
private static String TABLE_WORKSHOPS = "workshops";

public static String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static String COLUMN_TITLE= "title";
public static String COLUMN_BESCHRIJVING = "beschrijving";
public static final String COLUMN_MGT = "mgt";
public static final String COLUMN_DOC = "doc";
public static final String COLUMN_OOP = "oop";
public static final String COLUMN_BEGELEIDER = "begeleider";
public static final String COLUMN_DEELNEMERS = "deelnemers";
public static final String COLUMN_RONDE1 = "ronde1";
public static final String COLUMN_RONDE2 = "ronde2";
public static final String COLUMN_RONDE3 = "ronde3";
public static final String COLUMN_LOKAAL1 = "lokaal1";
public static final String COLUMN_LOKAAL2 = "lokaal2";
public static final String COLUMN_LOKAAL3 = "lokaal3";

public MyDbHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workshops(_id INT, title VARCHAR, beschrijving VARCHAR);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE workshops;");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workshops(_id INT, title VARCHAR, beschrijving VARCHAR);");
}


public void InsertValues()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO workshops VALUES(1, 'Title Would be Here', 'Here would be the description');");


    db.close();
}

public Cursor GetAllData()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM workshops;", null);
    return c;
}

}
```

I really hope someone can help me on this because I have no idea how to do it since I'm fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You receive the item position as `position` parameter

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent listClicked = new Intent(getActivity(), ListClicked.class);
        startActivity(listClicked);

        tv1 = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listClickedTitle);
        tv2 = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listClickedDescription); 

        //This is the position of the item clicked            
        int pos = position;

        //You also can have the item ID
        long itemID = id;

    }
});
```

Then you can get all the data from the Cursor with item position X

Comment: Where exactly should I put the pos as parameter and can I just retrieve data as I did with the list view? @Diego

Comment: How exactly would put them to a textview like that? @Diego Ramírez

Comment: As you already retrieve all data from that item, you can manage all that info in your item view, in the adapter, and then, when you handle the click, toggle detail views visibility. I could work in an example at night today, I'm at work now :P